# Sharepoint Excel Rest api is not working with workbook which includes % in name

Tags: excel, rest, sharepoint-2010, odata, sharepoint-2013

Here I am trying to use Excel Rest Service to get some data from SharePoint.

Excel file Name: UserData.xlsx

This excel have two workbook

1. Work Data
2. User Salary%

I am able to get work data by using below query

`.../sites/portal/_vti_bin/excelrest.aspx/Reports/UserData.xlsx/model/Ranges('''Work  Data''!A24|M24')?$format=atom`

So it means my URL creation logic is correct and hence I am able to get data in my C# program.

However I am not able to get data for second Workbook with below URL

`.../sites/portal/_vti_bin/excelrest.aspx/Reports/UserData.xlsx/model/Ranges(**'''User Salary%**''!A24|M24')?$format=atom`

I couldn't figure out why I am able to access the first workbook, but not my second; although, the URL looks same.

One reason may be that second workbook contains % (User Salary%), which might cause a problem, but I cannot rename workbook since it is created by different department.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try escaping the problem character by replacing the `%` in the worksheet name with `%25`  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: I tried using %25 but its not working       .../sites/portal/_vti_bin/excelrest.aspx/Reports/UserData.xlsx/model/Ranges('''User Salary%25''!A24|M24')?$format=atom

Comment: What does it do instead of work?  Error message?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while reading the values from Excel Sheet  "Risk Matrix". It is Space " " which is creating issue in Excel REST.

```
XYZ.xlsx/model/Ranges('Risk matrix!K15:L15')?$format=json
```

The thing worked for me is to rename the Excel Sheet name:

```
XYZ.xlsx/model/Ranges('Riskmatrix!K15:L15')?$format=json
```

I tried to search other approach but due to time constraint I had to do the above work around.

Comment: It appears that this restriction still applies... I am using an SDK wrapper for the ExcelOnline REST API and I am thrown an `Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException` when trying to add a table on a worksheet that contains a space in its name. 5 years later ...

Answer (score 0):

If the sheet name contains spaces it must be put in single quotes.
So even if that looks strange you need to use **two single quotes** at the beginning of your query argument:

```
XYZ.xlsx/model/Ranges(''Risk matrix'!K15:L15')?$format=json
```